# Need to make changes to security algorithms from md5 to SHA-256 HMAC php

Tags: php, md5, sha256

I am a newbie to world of web development and I have been ask by a friend to upgrade their payment gateway from md5 to SHA-256 HMAC.

I have tried to change it on my own, however I am getting errors when go to the secure gateway, I think there are some issue on my code that I not quiet understand

**Existing code:**

```
if($type == "Credit Card") {
    unset($_POST["type"]);
    unset($_POST["order_id"]);
    $SECURE_SECRET = "MIGS_SS";  
    $vpcURL = $_POST["virtualPaymentClientURL"] . "?";  
    unset($_POST["SubButL"]);
    unset($_POST["virtualPaymentClientURL"]); 
    $md5HashData = $SECURE_SECRET;
    ksort ($_POST);
    $appendAmp = 0;

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  if (strlen($value) > 0) {      
if ($appendAmp == 0) {
  $vpcURL .= urlencode($key) . '=' . urlencode($value);
  $appendAmp = 1;
  } else {
  $vpcURL .= '&' . urlencode($key) . "=" . urlencode($value);
}
  $md5HashData .= $value;
  }
}

if (strlen($SECURE_SECRET) > 0) {
  $vpcURL .= "&vpc_SecureHash=" . strtoupper(md5($md5HashData));
}

header("Location: ".$vpcURL);
} else {
header("Location: index.php?dz=eft&id=".$order_id."\n\n");
}
```

**The new code I got:**

```
            foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
         // create the hash input and URL leaving out any fields that have no  value
            if (strlen($value) > 0) {
        ?>
             <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo($key); ?>"  value="<?php    echo($value); ?>"/><br>
      <?php             
            if ((strlen($value) > 0) && ((substr($key, 0,4)=="vpc_") ||       (substr($key,0,5) =="user_"))) {
         $hashinput .= $key . "=" . $value . "&";
        }
        }

       }

       $hashinput = rtrim($hashinput, "&");
        ?>      
             <!-- attach SecureHash -->
             <input type="hidden" name="vpc_SecureHash"  value="<?php echo(strtoupper(hash_hmac('SHA256', $hashinput, pack('H*',$securesecret)))); ?>"/>
            <input type="hidden" name="vpc_SecureHashType" value="SHA256">
```

How can I use it in my code?

If you could u write the correct code here where I should change?

Comment: If you are a "newbie" to security and web development, it might be a poor idea to be working with crypto primitives and credit card payments.  Just my two cents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you changing entire code..

Just change `md5` function to `sha`.

```
if (strlen($SECURE_SECRET) > 0) {
  $vpcURL .= "&vpc_SecureHash=" . strtoupper(md5($md5HashData));
}
```

to

```
if (strlen($SECURE_SECRET) > 0) {
  $vpcURL .= "&vpc_SecureHash=" . strtoupper(sha1($md5HashData));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however getting a HTTP Status - 400 error...